# CiviCase dashboard shows cases for invisible contacts

Tags: civicase, permissions, dashboard

iam using CiviCRM 5.25 and Drupal 7.71. I have a bunch of acls running to limit the access to contacts, so with using CiviCase it controls the limited access for case managers to contacts, or more specific: to clients. therefore related permissions module is also running. Normally the limited access is working fine, even on the search pages (!).

But the CiviCase dashboard `civicrm/case?reset=1` is not working this way. The CiviCase dashboard show too much cases. As well the overview table as the activites results shows cases the case managers should not see, because the manager is not allowed to see many of this contacts (clients). If i hit a contact name, i get the permission issue and i can't access the contact, this is expected behaviour.

So, the permission on this page is set to "`access all cases and activites`", which should mean "**... for visible contacts**", but "**for visible contacts**" is not working. Is anyone who can confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the case dashboard permission is a bit hardcoded to just "all" or "my" cases, e.g. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/8036d43973a5d42b0722cc45cba3a9f88e9ce182/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php#L695

Comment: Does it mean its a bug or so? I mean, its skipping the on-board permission concept.

Comment: You could consider using a drupal view or custom dashboard instead and then you could also better show people what data items they really want.

Comment: I second Demerit's comment above, we found the case dashboard not quite fine-tuned enough ( we have LOTS of cases) and turned it off altogether. We went the VIews route with CiviCRMEntity.